# How to show the Tooltip even on disabled buttons with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tooltip, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular 6 app, I'm currently using the [Tooltip feature from ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip) to show tooltips.

I need to show the tooltips in some disabled buttons, however it does not work (it only works with non-disabled buttons).

Is there a way to change this behaviour and always show the tooltip (regardless if the item is disabled) ?

Comment: Check if the disabled button has pointer-events: none. If no other options, I would wrap my disabled button in a div and have to tooltip on it instead of the button.

Comment: @Francesco Borzì: have you found any solution for this ? do you have any demo for it ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI it's been a while I haven't investigated on this issue, however normally I post the solution when I find it myself, so probably not :(

Answer (score 4):

**Please read this article**: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/events-and-disabled-form-fields/

Probably Chrome and many other browsers stop emitting all mouse events on disabled form fields, including buttons.

I stuck in similar scenario and this Workaround worked very well for me

```
triggers="pointerenter:pointerout"
```

Depending on content used inside button it may require to add pointer-events: none; in CSS for them.

**Confirmed to work on following browser:**

```
Chrome 73+
FF 66+
IE 11+
Edge 42+
```

I hope it may help you!

Comment: If it works to anyone or you feel this could be answer then I would request you to please mark it as accepted answer so it will help other folks too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the example using disabled class I had success.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary mb-2 disabled "
                tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
                placement="top">
            Tooltip
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a demo or a stackblitz demo, to show that it is working this way ? if any class needed that you added, can you add a comment to explain them ?

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is pack button by span like the example below:

```
<span tooltip="ivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." placement="top">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary mb-2 disabled">
        Tooltip
    </button>
</span>
```